# How to change Linux to compile in C99 mode?

Tags: c

I need to change the compile mode to C99, is there any way to do this ?

I am using vim so it's not and IDE at all.

Comment: vim isn't a C compiler; you are going to need to get a C compiler in order to compiler C code

Comment: yea yea i know it .... some ppl may tell me to change it from the IDE

Comment: The point is that you need to be specifying what compiler you use rather than what IDE you use.

Comment: @XMasterrrr, if you open a terminal, type `gcc --version` and paste the output

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5

Answer (score 9):

I assume you use gcc. Use the `-std=c99` flag.

Comment: there is no other way to got it c99 without the flag?

Comment: @Xmasterrr How would you prefer to do it?

Comment: @Xmasterr: Can you describe more precisely how you go about compiling your code?

Comment: @Lucas why doesn't it compile with C99 mode by default ? I am using gcc on linux(fedora)

Answer (score 3):

Any POSIX complying system is supposed to have a compiler frontend named `c99`. On linux this is usually just a wrapper that sets the necessary options to `gcc`.

If you'd have to pass that to `make` you could give it `CC=c99` on the commandline. Or you could just add a line to your bashrc (or equivalent) of

```
export CC=c99
```

Comment: yea it works but i had to write it every time i open a new terminal

Comment: @XMasterrrr, this depends on your setting. You'd have to change write this in the appropriate configuration file for your shell. And then probably log out and reconnect to have this in effect.

Comment: I should read POSIX completely at some point. Did not know this :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you compile your C code from vim, but in any way, you need to create a make file and execute it to compile. You need to specify the C99 switch, however note that it is not fully implemented in GCC.

> Note that this standard is not yet
>   fully supported; see
>   http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/c99status.html
>   for more information

If you don't already have one, I included a generic make file that I use for C homeworks :

```
# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile
#
# Author: Yanick Rochon
# Date  : 2010-11-05
#
# Changelog :
#   0.01 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

# project name (generate executable with this name)
TARGET   = <executable name here>

CC       = gcc -c
# compiling flags here
CFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall -I.

LINKER   = gcc -o
# linking flags here
LFLAGS   = -std=c99 -Wall

SOURCES  := $(wildcard *.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:.c=*.o)
rm       = rm -f

$(TARGET): obj
    @$(LINKER) $(TARGET) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"

obj: $(SOURCES) $(INCLUDES)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCES)
    @echo "Compilation complete!"

clean:
    @$(rm) $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"
```

** **EDIT** **

I usually edit my C sources with GEdit and have a terminal opened (or I use the GEdit's terminal plugin) to compile (using make). You can also use a full grown IDE to edit your sources, such as SharpDevelop or Anjuta, but I find GEdit and a terminal to be my preferable dev tools for C. One reason being that I actually have to do everything myself (mostly) so I know what's going on :) The same can be achieved with Vim instead of GEdit.

Comment: so i can use this makefile as it's my original one ?

Comment: just place it where your .c files are and type `make` to compile. Note that this makefile does not compile sources in subdirectories, though

Answer (score 0):

export CFLAGS='-std=c99' && make $program

Comment: The answer is not complete, nor does it work directly from vim unless the user is using a Makefile.

Also a short explaination about why / how it works